# How to get the namespace of a node in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces

I'm propably doing something stupid here, I bet there is an easier way... I need to access namespace of a node. Elements in my xml looks for example like this:

```
<somenamespace:element name="SomeName">
```

Then in my xslt I access this elements with:

```
 <xsl:template  match="*[local-name()='element']">
    <xsl:variable name="nodename">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name(current())"/>
    </xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($nodename,':')">
```

Well, of course it doesn't work, because there is no "somenamespace" namespace even in template match...

Can anyone guide me, what am I looking for?

Comment: You need to tell us what you are looking for and what is not working.

Comment: Where did you find `local-namespace` function?

Comment: Ow gosh, sory, it's a mistake. Corrected - I meant local-name. I'm looking for a way to access the "somenamespace" prefix. It's not working, because local-name returns only the "element" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `name` function, e..g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
```

returns `somenamespace:element`

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me as if you want to test whether the node is in a non-null namespace. The correct way to do that is

```
namespace-uri() != ''
```

You shouldn't be looking at whether the lexical name has a prefix or contains a colon, because if the node is in a namespace then it can be written either with a prefix or without, and the two forms are equivalent.

But I'm guessing as to what your real, underlying, requirement is.

Answer (score 3):

From OP's comment:

> I'm looking for a way to access the "somenamespace" prefix.

**You can access the prefix of the current node name by**:

```
substring-before(name(), ':")
```

**Another way**:

```
substring-before(name(), local-name())
```

The above produces either the empty string '' or the prefix, followed by the ':' character.

**To check if the name of the current node is prefixed**:

```
not(name() = local-name())
```